# mod_pagespeed combine css on other domain

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I've been looking at mod_pagespeed as a way to speed up my site.  I currently load my CSS/JS from a separate domain to speed up loading of those resources.  However, I like to break up my CSS/JS into useful functional chunks.  This means, in the worst case scenarios I may have half a dozen CSS files and the same number of JS files being included on a single page.

So my question is.  How can I use mod_pagespeed to continue loading files from a different domain but also use the combine_css/combine_js directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you either need to run mod_pagespeed on both sites (and authorize both sites) or to rewrite the CSS/JS from the other domain to the one that runs mod_pagespeed.

For example, if you have mod_pagespeed installed on both your main site (`http://www.example.com`) and your static-content site (`http://static.example.com`), you can add:

```
ModPagespeedDomain http://static.example.com
```

to your `pagespeed.conf` file on `www.example.com` and this will authorize mod_pagespeed to rewrite those resources and continue to serve them from that domain. See http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/domains.html#auth_domains for doc.

If you want mod_pagespeed to rewrite resources from your static domain to your main domain you can add:

```
ModPagespeedDomain http://static.example.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain www.example.com static.example.com
```

which will tell mod_pagespeed to rewrite files in `static.example.com` and move them to `www.example.com`.

If you have more questions, feel free to contact us on our official email list: https://groups.google.com/group/mod-pagespeed-discuss

-Shawn Ligocki (mod_pagespeed team)

Comment: The first example is pretty much exactly what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @sligocki I have same problem . When combine_css,combine_javascript disabled everything works fine . Note in my setup static.example.com is Nginx and www.example.com is Apache . Any help ? Also asked here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod-pagespeed-discuss/ZybktKbCKIE