# mod_pagespeed with multiple domains or subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I was wondering about the usage of pagespeed with multiple domains or subdomain, and whether it works or not.

I found some question [here at SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885632/mod-pagespeed-combine-css-on-other-domain) with similar things I want to achieve except that I want to do that with subdomains or multiple domains.

I tried to use the following to make things work yet not sure if it does!!

```
ModPagespeedDomain http://www.example-1.com #  domain 1 where to get images from

ModPagespeedDomain http://static.example.com #  subdomain 1 where to get js files from

ModPagespeedDomain http://resources.example.com #  subdomain 2 where to get css from
```

now I want to know if the following setting is ok or not:

```
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain http://www.example.com   http://www.example1.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain http://www.example.com   http://static.example.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain http://www.example.com   http://resources.example.com
```

or should that be inline to the main domain only instead of listing them one by one...

**so my question is this configuration correct?? if not, how do I correct it??**

I hope it is not confusing...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

- [`ModPagespeedDomain`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains) directives work if you have mod_pagespeed installed on all three domains (for example, if they are all just separate `VirtualHost`s on the same machine.). This will rewrite all resources on all 3 domains no matter which one the HTML is loaded from. **Do not use these directives if mod_pagespeed is not running on the 3 resource domains.**
- [`ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#MapProxyDomain) will rewrite URLs from these 3 domains into `www.example.com`. You would usually use this if you do not have mod_pagespeed installed on the 3 resource domains, but you do on `www.example.com`. Note: You probably want something more like:

  ```
  ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain http://www.example.com/images/   http://www.example1.com
  ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain http://www.example.com/js/   http://static.example.com
  ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain http://www.example.com/css/   http://resources.example.com
  ```

  The subdirectories are necessary to make sure that mod_pagespeed knows which resources map back to which domains. [Read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#MapProxyDomain) for more details.
- [`ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#mapping_rewrite) is probably not what you want. That directive is basically only used for CDN configuration. It would rewrite URLs from the 3 resource domains to `www.example.com`, but would not be able to respond to the request for those rewritten resources (It assumes that the domain you rewrite to is a pull CDN).

For more information, you can read the full [PageSpeed Authorizing and Mapping Domains documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains).